# Docker | Build getting exiting on Interactive Shell

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a version of `Swoole` with `php7.3-alpine` image.

When running, everything builds correctly and all of the extensions get installed correctly. However, when it comes to doing `docker-compose up` I get stuck in `Interactive shell` and then exits with code 0 so the container doesn't actually boot up correctly.

Is there anything I can do to stop this issue and stop it from running the interactive shell?

```
FROM composer:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo

COPY . /app/

RUN composer install \
        --no-ansi \
        --no-dev \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-progress \
        --optimize-autoloader \
        --ignore-platform-reqs

RUN rm -rf docker/ composer.json composer.lock && \
    touch /app/storage/logs/lumen.log

FROM php:7.3-alpine

ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS=0 \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES=7963 \
    PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION=192

RUN set -ex \
    && apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache libffi-dev icu libsodium \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies icu-dev g++ make autoconf libsodium-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl install swoole redis sodium \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis swoole sodium \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql intl \
    && cd  / && rm -fr /src \
    && apk del build-dependencies \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

COPY --from=builder --chown=www-data:www-data /app /var/www

COPY docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 1215
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:1215"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

output

```
web_1       | Interactive shell
web_1       |
web_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: If the docker image builds with no issue you need to provide the docker-compose.yml file in order to debug further

Comment: Added docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `CMD` at the end of your dockerfile the last stage which will be used as a starting point for the container that you will run it. you can check the following [URL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

The Interactive Shell is there because of the original `CMD` of `php:7.3-alpine` which is `php -a` that gives:

```
Interactive shell

php >
```

You need to define your own CMD that starts your application and check the logs if it was not working

Comment: Hi I did this and did `CMD ["php", "artisan","swoole:http","start"]` but I get the same issue.

Comment: the exist status is still `0` ?

Comment: also have you checked docker logs of this container ?

Comment: Exit code is 1 when I put that in because the service is still running, removing that though I get the interactive shell issue.

Comment: i have updated the answer regarding the exist code 0. you need to check the error log when you add your own `CMD`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189271/discussion-between-tallent123-and-mostafa-hussein).

Comment: @tallent123 I tested the image on the repository and its working

Comment: Just added `RUN composer install` to the dockerfile to avoid the load error and the current output: `Swoole http server started: <http://0.0.0.0:5000>`

Comment: That's very strange as to why it doesn't work on mine then :(

Comment: try to build it with `--no-cache` what i have done: just switched to feature/swoole branch then added the RUN composer install before cmd then started the build process and  tried a container its running correctly